# How do i install .net core 3.1 in my linux based ec2 instance

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am trying my hands on the aws instance configurations.

as i am new to this . i was trying to install .net 3.1 core .

followed the below code

```
sudo su -
yum install -y libunwind libicu
curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=835019
mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && sudo tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

but nothing worked . 
dont exactly know the working of the above code , would like to know it .

and also would like to install .net3.1 core on my ec2 instance.

Could you please help me out in this ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: my local system in on windows 10 . 
my ec2 is on linux

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams user the basic Linux 2 ami

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon Linux 2, all you need is to set the Microsoft Repo:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to install packages in a native Linux way.

As Amazon Linux is RHEL-based, you can refer to the following commands.

**SDK**

```
sudo yum install scl-utils
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-dotnet-rpms
yum install rh-dotnet31 -y
scl enable rh-dotnet31 bash
source scl_source enable rh-dotnet31
```

**Runtime**

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-dotnet-rpms
yum install rh-dotnet31-aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 -y
scl enable rh-dotnet31-aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 bash
source scl_source enable rh-dotnet31-aspnetcore-runtime-3.1
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-rhel#rhel-7-